# JBoss 6 Can Not Find an Installed Certifiate

Tags: https, jboss6.x, truststore

I have created a keystore with a self signed certificate, exported the certificate, and re-imported the certificate with an alias of the IP address.

I want to make a call from inside this server to another service on this server at  address]/.....

I can not get the client side of the call to trust itself.  How do I specify the truststore?

Here is the key part of the server.xml:

```
  <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
       keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/mykey"
       keystorePass="changeit" 
       truststoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/mykey"
       truststorePass="changeit" 
       sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

I get this error on attempting to use https to call a service from this server, to itself.

PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer: jBoss 6 is using the Java runtime for the client truststore, not its own file.  Putting the certificate in the Java environment worked.

I would like to learn if I get set the truststore in jBoss's configuration for the connector as I have above...